# VSC GitHub Copilot TAB no responde las sugerencias de CoPilot

Tags: javascript, typescript, vscode, github

Muestra las sugerencias de copilot pero no puedo seleccionar a ninguna sugerencia presionando Tab uso Visual Studio Code en Windows. Si acepta Alt+] (or Alt+[) para mostrar sugerencias alternativas .También muestra sugerencias múltiples con Ctrl+Enter pero tampoco logro aceptar ninguna .Las extensiones que uso son pocas y en general para Angular  [image: extenciones1]las muestro en las fotos.Gracias me interesa poder usar esta herramienta
[image: extenciones2]

Mi settings.json de VSC

```
{
    "editor.fontSize": 13,
    "sonarlint.ls.javaHome": "c:\\Users\\NESTDAN\\.vscode\\extensions\\sonarsource.sonarlint_managed-jre\\jre\\jdk-11.0.14.1+1-jre",
    "update.enableWindowsBackgroundUpdates": false,
    "update.mode": "none",
    "update.showReleaseNotes": false,
    "extensions.autoCheckUpdates": false,
    "extensions.autoUpdate": false,
    "editor.accessibilitySupport": "off",
    "workbench.colorTheme": "Light High Contrast",
    "workbench.colorCustomizations": {
        
        "statusBar.background": "#4d7a52",
        "sideBar.background":"#c1c279",
        "sideBarTitle.foreground":"#4a5d48",
        "sideBarSectionHeader.background":"#64814c",
        "sideBarSectionHeader.foreground":"#e5e761",
        "editorGroup.emptyBackground":"#0d7e18",
        "editorGroupHeader.tabsBorder":"#e5e761",
        "editorGroup.border":"#0d7e18",
        "editorGroupHeader.tabsBackground":"#eeeee8",
        "tab.activeBackground":"#dddd6d",
        "tab.border":"#575812",
        "tab.unfocusedActiveBorder":"#0d7e18",
        
        "tab.inactiveBackground":"#ceddd0",
        "menubar.selectionForeground":"#0d7e18",
        "menubar.selectionBackground":"#9ac79f",
        "menu.background":"#87a88b",
        "menu.border":"#123115",
        "tab.unfocusedActiveBackground":"#bfdbc3",
        "tab.inactiveForeground":"#0d7e18",
        "activityBar.inactiveForeground":"#0d7e18",
        "selection.background":"#f8f5f5",
        "toolbar.activeBackground":"#cce9d0"
        
    },
    "editor.inlineSuggest.enabled": true
}
```

Comment: a mi me pasa mucho, es tan molesto pues después debo borrar los plugin y si aun asi no funciona, reinstalar por eso te aconsejo mantenerte sincronisado con la cuneta de github o microsoft

Comment: @john si desactivas los plugin y reinstalas funciona?

Comment: eso es lo que me ha tocado hacer por experiencia, o cambias la carpeta de preferencias en tu carpeta de usuario  C:\Users\TuUsuario\.vscode  puedes probar cambiando el nombre, despues abres el VS y ves si funciona, sino puedes reinstalar

Comment: gracias intento ver si funciona en mi configuración

Answer (score -1):

Como workarround, en windows 11, he puesto el teclado en "Ingles (Estados Unidos) y me ha funcionado bien la combinación <kbd>alt</kbd><kbd>]</kbd> para las sugerencias de copilot.

Comment: si acepta combinación de teclas para sugerencias como lo menciono en la consulta pero lo que no acepta es Tab igual lo pruebo